# Title not setting with json. Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uinavigationcontroller

I want to set the title of my navigation bar with a json title.

I tried:

```
[self setTitle:[self.defineJsonDataforSurveyQuestion objectForKey:@"SurveyName"]];
[self.navigationController setTitle:[self.defineJsonDataforSurveyQuestion objectForKey:@"SurveyName"]];
```

It works if manually set the title but I get nothing with the json. I know I am getting the correct value and and parsing the json right because it shows correct in the NSLog.

I have no errors and the title just comes up blank.

```
2013-05-25 13:37:26.863 [1657:907] Survey name for title:Filter Inspection
```

Please help.

Comment: In which method did you implement your code for setting the title?

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Show us the `NSLog()` output please ;)

Answer (score 3):

objectForKey: returns an object, which could be an NSString, but it doesn't have to be. When you print it with NSLog, NSLog calls 'describe' on the object, that way you still get something sensible in your log, but setTitle: doesn't do that of course, it expects an NSString object.

```
id title = [self.defineJsonDataforSurveyQuestion objectForKey:@"SurveyName"];
if ([[title class] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

  [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem  setTitle:title];

} else {
  NSLog(@"title is not a string, but %@!", [title class]);
}
```